# if <var> is None: doesn't seem to wotk

Tags: python, if-statement, nonetype

***Disclaimer:** I am very new to python, and have no idea what i am doing, i am teaching myself from the web.*

I have some code that looks like this

**Code:**

```
from request import get # Ed: added for clarity

myurl = URLBASE + args.key
response = get(myurl)

# check key is valid
json = response.text # Ed: this is a requests.Response object 
print(json)

if json is None:
    sys.exit("Problem getting API data, check your key")

print("how did i get here")
```

**Output:**

```
null
how did i get here
```

But I have no idea how that is possible ... it literally says it is null in the print, but then doesn't match in the 'if'.  Any help would be appreciated.

thx

Comment: You never parsed the JSON, so it’s the string `"null"`. Not sure what `get` is, but try `json = response.json`.

Comment: A string `"null"` is not the object `None`.

Comment: The only thing that is `None` is `None` itself.

Comment: @Ry- Has got the right idea, but you need to use `response.json()` because `response.json` will just send you into a similar trap.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If `response.text` is supposed to be json, then use the `json.loads()` function to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

So I am sure I still don't fully understand, but this "fixes" my problem.

The `requests.Response object` has Property/Method `json` - so i should have been using that, ***thanks wim***, instead of `text`.  So changing the code to this *(below)*, as suggested, makes the code work.

```
from request import get

myurl = URLBASE + args.key
response = get(myurl)

# check key is valid
json = response.json()

if json is None:
    sys.exit("Problem getting API data, check your key")

print("how did i get here")
```

The question (for me inquisitively) remains, how would I do an if statement to determine if a string is null?

Thanks to Ry and wim, for their help.

Comment: `if some_string == "null"`. In this case the string is not the `null` object (which does not exist in Python, it's called `None`), it is a string that has the contents `"null"`; that is, the characters `n`, `u`, `l`, `l` in that order.

Comment: Thanks @Adam Smith, for taking the time,  That works (as you probably know) and now I have tested it in the code and was able to make it work, and understand it and python a bit better.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: crap one question can a string be null?  or if the string is null is it populated with 'null'?  what is you wanted a string with the contents "null" or if you wanted to compare stings how would you tell the difference between "null" (string) and <null>  (actually) null (or empty)

Comment: There is only one null object in Python, and it is the singleton `None`. A string with the contents `"null"` is just a regular string. An empty string looks like `""`

Comment: (a "null string" looks like `None`, the same as a "null anything-else." This was in fact your problem, as the response text was the text "null" which has no special meaning in Python. It was intended to be parsed as JSON, which correctly recognizes it as the null object and deserializes appropriately to `None`)